# Proxy to transform an XML body of an http request?

Tags: proxy, webserver, xml, xslt, transform

I have a calling system that I cannot easily change. It sends an http request (actually SOAP) with two elements in the wrong order.

This is easy to fix with an XSL transform.

I'd like to implement a proxy web server that transforms the request via XSL. Apache or nginx for the web server, ideally, but I can look at others.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I worked something out.

I used mod_ext_filter in Apache, and SaxonHE for the actual transformation.  This is not a high performance solution (it starts the processor for every request), but it suffices for now.

The key lines for the config are:

```
ExtFilterDefine soap-fix mode=input cmd="/usr/bin/java -cp /saxon-install-location/saxon-he-10.3.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:/whereever-you-want/fix.xsl -s:- "
SetInputFilter soap-fix
```

and then standard proxy stuff to forward the modified request on.